# Golang passing a variable by reference to a structure member value

Tags: pointers, struct, reference, go

I am having difficulties passing a value to a struct by reference or by passing a pointer. I will outline what I am trying to achieve:

```
type FooStruct struct {
    foo1, foo2, foo3 int //etc
    connection *net.Conn
}

func(session FooStruct) Run(conn *net.Conn) {
    session.connection = conn
    session.connection.RemoteAddr()
    ......
}

func main() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8484")
    connection, err := server.Accept()
    foo := FooStruct{}
    foo.Run(&connection)
}
```

The above is an example of what I am trying to achive I only want to pass a reference pointer to the connection variable in the struct. I have tried reading the documentation and going through the tutorial but I have become confused.

When compiling I get the error - session.connection.RemoteAddr undefined (type * net.Conn has no field or method RemoteAddr). It does have that method as when copying the variable it works fine. However that is not what I want to do.

Comment: `net.Conn` is an interface, not a struct. Your struct is `net.TCPConn`, which implements the `net.Conn` interface. What you are essentially doing it passing a pointer to an interface, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: There's also a typo in your struct definition (an extraneous comma).

Comment: So am I right in thinking then all I have to do is change connection *net.Conn to connection *net.TCPConn and func(session FooStruct) Run(conn *net.Conn) to func(session FooStruct) Run(conn *net.TCPConn)? How would I go about modifying the main function work with the new struct as I can no longer use the net.Conn interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `net.Conn` is an interface, not a struct, you should pass and store it directly. Like this:

```
type FooStruct struct {
    foo1, foo2, foo3 int
    connection       net.Conn
}

func(session *FooStruct) Run(conn net.Conn) {
    session.connection = conn
    session.connection.RemoteAddr()
}

func main() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8484")
    connection, err := server.Accept()
    foo := FooStruct{}
    foo.Run(connection)
}
```

See also the Go FAQ entry on [passing interfaces to pointers](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface).

Also note that I changed the receiver of the `Run` method to a pointer, [which is generally what you want](http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers).

Comment: Here is a [discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/DwFGXLYgatY) on why never to pass interfaces by pointer.

Comment: Thanks that works. Cheers for linking the corresponding parts of the documentation I shall enjoy reading those.